# How can I tell if I'm running on x64?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

I just got a bug report for an issue that only occurs when the program is running "on a 64-bit machine."  Now, Delphi doesn't produce 64-bit code, so theoretically that shouldn't matter, but apparently it does in this case.  I think I have a workaround, but it will break things on 32-bit Windows, so I need some way to tell:

1. If I'm running on a x64 or an x86 processor and
2. If I'm running under a 64-bit version of Windows under Win32 emulation or native Win32 on a 32-bit OS.

Does anyone know how I can get those answers from within my app?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mason, you can use [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28VS.85%29.aspx) (WOW64 is the x86 emulator that allows 32-bit Windows-based applications to run seamlessly on 64-bit Windows)

```
Uses Windows;

type
  WinIsWow64 = function( Handle: THandle; var Iret: BOOL ): Windows.BOOL; stdcall;


function IAmIn64Bits: Boolean;
var
  HandleTo64BitsProcess: WinIsWow64;
  Iret                 : Windows.BOOL;
begin
  Result := False;
  HandleTo64BitsProcess := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'), 'IsWow64Process');
  if Assigned(HandleTo64BitsProcess) then
  begin
    if not HandleTo64BitsProcess(GetCurrentProcess, Iret) then
    Raise Exception.Create('Invalid handle');
    Result := Iret;
  end;
end;
```

Bye.

Comment: Is this allowed by windows' UAC when running app has medium or low permissions?

Comment: I answer to my own comment: Yes! because kernel32.dll is part of every Delphi process

Answer (score 8):

I see the your question 2 (are you running on Win64?) is already answered. Just keep in mind that for your code to be future-proof, you need to consider that in a (hypothetical) 64-bit Delphi app running on Win64, IsWow64Process would also return FALSE.

As regards your first question - are you on a 64-bit CPU -, you can check the hardware for the respective CPUID feature flag, like in the code below.

```
function Is64BitProcessor: boolean;
begin
  Result:=false;
  if CpuidAvailable = true then Result := Has64BitFeatureFlag;
end;
```

which uses the following two low-level functions:

```
function CPUIDavailable:boolean;
asm // if EFLAGS bit 21 can be modified then CPUID is available
    pushfd              //Save Flags
          pushfd        //Copy flags to EAX
          pop eax
          mov ecx,eax   //Make another copy in ECX
          btc eax,21    //Complement bit 21
          push eax      //Copy EAX to flags
          popfd
          pushfd        //Copy flags back to EAX
          pop eax
          cmp eax,ecx   //Compare "old" flags value with potentially modified "new" value
          setne al      //Set return value
    popfd               //Restore flags
end;
```

function Has64BitFeatureFlag: boolean;
asm
  //IF CPUID.80000001h.EDX[bit29]=1 THEN it's a 64bit processor.
  //But we first need to check whether there's a function 80000001h.
  push ebx                  //Save EBX as CPUID will modify EBX
  push esi                  //Save ESI as we'll use ESI internally

```
xor eax,eax             //Setting EAX = input param for CPUID to 0
cpuid                   //Call CPUID.0
                        //Returns -> EAX = max "standard" EAX input value
mov esi, eax            //Saving MaxStdInput Value

mov eax,80000000h       //Setting EAX = input param for CPUID to $80000000
cpuid                   //Call CPUID.80000000h
                        //Returns -> EAX = max "extended" EAX input value
                        //If 80000000h call is unsupported (no 64-bit processor),
                        //cpuid should return the same as in call 0
cmp eax, esi
je @No64BitProcessor    //IF EAX{MaxExtInput} = ESI{MaxStdInput} THEN goto No64BitProcessor;

cmp eax, 80000001h
jb @No64BitProcessor    //IF EAX{MaxExtInput} < $80000001 THEN goto No64BitProcessor;

mov eax,80000001h       //Call $80000001 is supported, setting EAX:=$80000001
cpuid                   //Call CPUID.80000001h
                        //Checking "AMD long mode"/"Intel EM64T" feature bit (i.e., 64bit processor)
bt edx, 29              //by checking CPUID.80000001h.EDX[bit29]
setc al                 //IF Bit29=1 then AL{Result}:=1{true; it's a 64-bit processor}
jmp @Exit               //Exit {Note that Delphi may actually recode this as POP ESI; POP EBX; RET}
```

@No64BitProcessor:
    xor eax, eax            //Result{AL/EAX}:=0{false; it's a 32-bit processor};
 @Exit:
  pop esi                   //Restore ESI
  pop ebx                   //Restore EBX
end;

EDIT1: A note on `CPUIDavailable`: This is of course assuming a >= 32-bit x86 processor (80386 or later), but Delphi Win32 code won't run on earlier machines anyway. The CPUID instruction was introduced with late 80486 processors.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the existence of and then call [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The linked MSDN page shows the required code.

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN page says:

> For compatibility with operating systems that do not support this
>   function, call GetProcAddress to detect whether IsWow64Process is
>   implemented in Kernel32.dll. If GetProcAddress succeeds, it is safe to
>   call this function. Otherwise, WOW64 is not present. Note that this
>   technique is not a reliable way to detect whether the operating system
>   is a 64-bit version of Windows because the Kernel32.dll in current
>   versions of 32-bit Windows also contains this function.

Which means:  this is a new function and you have to be careful statically linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Delphi can now compile Win64, I'd like to share my solution:

```
function WindowsBits: integer;

  function IsWow64: Boolean;
  {$IFDEF WIN64}
  begin
    // Native 64 Bit App means OS and CPU is 64 Bit, too.
    result := false;
  {$ELSE}
  type
    TIsWow64Process = function( // Type of IsWow64Process API fn
      Handle: Windows.THandle; var Res: Windows.BOOL
    ): Windows.BOOL; stdcall;
  var
    IsWow64Result: Windows.BOOL;      // Result from IsWow64Process
    IsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process;  // IsWow64Process fn reference
  begin
    // Try to load required function from kernel32
    IsWow64Process := Windows.GetProcAddress(
      Windows.GetModuleHandle('kernel32'), 'IsWow64Process'
    );
    if Assigned(IsWow64Process) then
    begin
      // Function is implemented: call it
      if not IsWow64Process(
        Windows.GetCurrentProcess, IsWow64Result
      ) then
        raise SysUtils.Exception.Create('IsWow64: bad process handle');
      // Return result of function
      Result := IsWow64Result;
    end
    else
      // Function not implemented: can't be running on Wow64
      Result := False;
  {$ENDIF}
  end;

begin
  {$IFDEF WIN64}
  result := 64;
  {$ELSE}
  if IsWow64 then
    result := 64
  else
    result := 32;
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

At the beginning of the first function you need to add

```
if SizeOf(Pointer)=8 then
  Exit(True); // Current app is 64 bit
```

Comment: The question is about how to tell if the windows OS is 64-bit, not if the application is 64-bit.

Answer (score -2):

**if `sizeof(IntPtr) == 8`** you're a 64-bit application on 64-bit Windows (**edit:** applies only to Delphi Prism)

**else if [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx) succeeds and returns true**, you're a 32-bit application on 
64-bit Windows

**else** you're on 32-bit Windows

Comment: First part isn't applicable, since Delphi doesn't compile 64-bit applications.

Comment: Doesn't Delphi Prism build .Net applications to IL? :-)

Comment: Yes, but Delphi and Delphi Prism are two different languages.  When someone just says "Delphi", they usually mean the native version.

Comment: If we go to 128bit in the future you will detect it as x86 since it's not 8 bytes.

Comment: @Remko you are technically correct, my answer will fail because it doesn't know how to deal with >64-bit OS. Then again, it'll fail in general to detect whether it's 128-bit app, or a 64-bit WOW app in 128-bit OS, or a 32-bit WOW app in 64-bit WOW emulator on 128-bit OS anyway. And I think you would be hard pressed to update my answer right now for detection of any app running on 128-bit OS, for the simple reason there's no correct way to detect something that does not exist yet.