# How to get information about the computer? [32bit or 64bit]

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, delphi-2007

How I can get information about Windows OS type? Is it 32bit or 64bit? How I can get this information programatically?

Comment: "compiuter"? "abaout"? "programory"? Please take the time to read your question before you post them.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: StackOverflow is international forum and you can't expect perfect english from everyone - just fix the annoying grammar errors.

Comment: @Serg: imperfect English and simple typos are two different things. I'm pretty sure that "abaout" is the latter. I don't have any problem at all with imperfect English (I'm not a native speaker myself).

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436185/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-on-x64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `GetProcAddress()` to check the availability of the [`IsWow64Process()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28VS.85%29.aspx) function at runtime, like so:

```
function Is64BitWindows: boolean;
type
  TIsWow64Process = function(hProcess: THandle; var Wow64Process: BOOL): BOOL;
    stdcall;
var
  DLLHandle: THandle;
  pIsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process;
  IsWow64: BOOL;
begin
  Result := False;
  DllHandle := LoadLibrary('kernel32.dll');
  if DLLHandle <> 0 then begin
    pIsWow64Process := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'IsWow64Process');
    Result := Assigned(pIsWow64Process)
      and pIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess, IsWow64) and IsWow64;
    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
  end;
end;
```

because that function is only available on Windows versions that do have a 64 bit flavour. Declaring it as `external` would prevent your application from running on Windows 2000 or Windows XP pre SP2.

**Edit:**

Chris has posted a comment about caching the result for performance reasons. This may not be necessary for this particular API function, because *kernel32.dll*  will always be there (and I can't imagine a program that would even load without it), but for other functions things may be different. So here's a version that caches the function result:

```
function Is64BitWindows: boolean;
type
  TIsWow64Process = function(hProcess: THandle; var Wow64Process: BOOL): BOOL;
    stdcall;
var
  DLLHandle: THandle;
  pIsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process;
const
  WasCalled: BOOL = False;
  IsWow64: BOOL = False;
begin
  if not WasCalled then begin
    DllHandle := LoadLibrary('kernel32.dll');
    if DLLHandle <> 0 then begin
      pIsWow64Process := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'IsWow64Process');
      if Assigned(pIsWow64Process) then
        pIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess, IsWow64);
      WasCalled := True;
      FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
    end;
  end;
  Result := IsWow64;
end;
```

Caching this function result is safe, as the API function will either be there or not, and its result can't change on the same Windows installation. It is even safe to call this concurrently from multiple threads, as two threads finding `WasCalled` to be `False` will both call the function, write the same result to the same memory location, and only afterwards set `WasCalled` to `True`.

Comment: It will be a good idea to cache the result if the program needs to know the answer multiple times.  i.e. you wouldn't want to call this in a loop, as LoadLibrary will be expensive, particularly when it doesn't find anything.   I'm not knocking the solution, just giving advice on the usage case.

Comment: This code will only compile if assignable/writable constants are enabled in the project settings.  To avoid being sensitive to this compiler setting, either introduce directives to ensure this compiler behaviour is set (and restored) as required around this code, or better yet, I'd suggest using a unit variable for the cached result (using an integer avoids needing to use two such variables: e.g. declare initialised = -1 for "not set", set = 0 for Win32 set = 1 for Win64).

Answer (score 12):

```
function IsWin64: Boolean;
var
  IsWow64Process : function(hProcess : THandle; var Wow64Process : BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
  Wow64Process : BOOL;
begin
  Result := False;
  IsWow64Process := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(Kernel32), 'IsWow64Process');
  if Assigned(IsWow64Process) then begin
    if IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess, Wow64Process) then begin
      Result := Wow64Process;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

If a) you're on windows and b) you can access the registry then HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion should be informative.

Comment: Sorry, but no registry. I am using windows

Comment: @gedO: You are contradicting yourself.  Windows means registry.  Try running "regedit" from the start menu.

Answer (score 2):

```
function TForm2.Arch: string;
begin
if TOSVersion.Architecture=arIntelX86 then
   Result := '32-bit' Else  Result := '64-bit'
end;
```

Comment: TOSVersion was introduced on XE2, the question is about Delphi 2007.

Comment: @bummi Actually the question doesn't specify what version of Delphi. It might have in the past, but not right now. So this answer is valid :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `IsWow64Process`, the [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340(VS.85).aspx) API function may be of interest to you (it's defined in the `Windows` unit) to find out more about the CPU you're on (or you can use assembly and `CPUID`).

Answer (score 1):

for delphi XE+

```
Uses System.SysUtils

Function IsWin64Or32: string;
Begin
   if Pos( '64-bit', TOSVersion.ToString ) > 0 then
     Result := '64-bit'
   Else
     Result := '32-bit';
End;
```

Example

```
lbl1.Caption := IsWin64Or32;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to call Win32 function in Delphi.

But if you write a 32-bit program, you can call the Win32 API IsWow64Process to know if you are in a 64-bit OS.

Of course, if you write a 64-bit exe, it will only run on 64-bit Windows, so there is no need to ask.

Comment: Good luck writing a 64-bit exe with Delphi.  ;)

Comment: Doing it just now. (2015)

Answer (score 0):

//not tested but u can try this

```
is64 := (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('ProgramW6432') <> '');
```

Comment: This question is tagged `delphi`, and does not have any mention of .net or Java. Therefore, you can't assume that `Environment` is available. Please read the tags before answering questions to make sure that your answer applies to them. If you're not sure,  you probably shouldn't be  answering the question. :-)

Comment: A Delphi coder would get there, noticing that it must have a defined Object Environment, therefore he will just remove it:
is64 := ({Environment.}GetEnvironmentVariable('ProgramW6432') <> '');

thank you!