# Automatically resize a Delphi button

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-2010, autosize

I want to dynamically change the caption on a `TButton`. The problem is that `TButton` doesn't resize itself if the caption is too long to fit on the button; so the text bleeds over the edges of the button.

How can I get the button to change size to fit the caption?

Some ideas:

- Use a different button component that can resize itself. Is there one?
- Subclass `TButton` and set `AutoSize=True` (haven't tried this, don't know if it will work).
- Calculate the size of the caption in pixels and manually change the width every time I change the caption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up going with option 3 ("Calculate the size of the caption in pixels and manually change the width every time I change the caption")

My code looks somthing like this:

```
// Called from the form containing the button
button.Caption := newCaption;
button.Width := self.Canvas.TextWidth(newCaption);
```

Answer (score 18):

Subclass `TButton`, make the already present `AutoSize` property public, and implement `CanAutoSize`:

```
type
  TButton = class(StdCtrls.TButton)
  private
    procedure CMFontchanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_FONTCHANGED;
    procedure CMTextchanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
  protected
    function CanAutoSize(var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer): Boolean; override;
  public
    property AutoSize;
  end;

function TButton.CanAutoSize(var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer): Boolean;
const
  WordBreak: array[Boolean] of Cardinal = (0, DT_WORDBREAK);
var
  DC: HDC;
  R: TRect;
  SaveFont: HFONT;
  DrawFlags: Cardinal;
begin
  DC := GetDC(Handle);
  try
    SetRect(R, 0, 0, NewWidth - 8, NewHeight - 8);
    SaveFont := SelectObject(DC, Font.Handle);
    DrawFlags := DT_LEFT or DT_CALCRECT or WordBreak[WordWrap];
    DrawText(DC, PChar(Caption), Length(Caption), R, DrawFlags);
    SelectObject(DC, SaveFont);
    NewWidth := R.Right + 8;
    NewHeight := R.Bottom + 8;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TButton.CMFontchanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  AdjustSize;
end;

procedure TButton.CMTextchanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  AdjustSize;
end;
```

#### Update:

To address [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678029/automatically-resize-a-delphi-button/9678981#comment12297198_9678981) on why the hard coded 8 pixels: Simply put, it looks just fine. But I did a little visual research on border widths of buttons:

```
   Button state               Windows XP         Windows 7
                              Classic  Themed    Classic  Themed
   Focused, incl. focus rect     5        4         5        3
   Focused, excl. focus rect     3        4         3        3
   Not focused                   2        2         2        2
   Disabled                      2        1         2        2
```

To take the operating system into account, see [Getting the Windows version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8144599/757830). Theming could be taken into account by evaluating `Themes.ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled`. When true, the content rect reserved for the text can be obtained with [`GetThemeBackgroundContentRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773375(v=vs.85).aspx) which is wrapped by the `ThemeServices` variable:

```
uses
  Themes;
var
  DC: HDC;
  Button: TThemedButton;
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;
  R: TRect;
begin
  DC := GetDC(Button2.Handle);
  try
    SetRect(R, 0, 0, Button2.Width, Button2.Height);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(R.Right - R.Left));
    Button := tbPushButtonNormal;
    Details := ThemeServices.GetElementDetails(Button);
    R := ThemeServices.ContentRect(DC, Details, R);
```

Repeating my test with this routine shows a constant border size of 3 pixels in either version and with any button state. Thus 8 pixels of total margin leaves 1 pixel breathing space for the text.

And to take the font size into account, I suggest the following change:

```
function TButton.CanAutoSize(var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer): Boolean;
const
  WordBreak: array[Boolean] of Cardinal = (0, DT_WORDBREAK);
var
  DC: HDC;
  Margin: Integer;
  R: TRect;
  SaveFont: HFONT;
  DrawFlags: Cardinal;
begin
  DC := GetDC(Handle);
  try
    Margin := 8 + Abs(Font.Height) div 5;
    SetRect(R, 0, 0, NewWidth - Margin, NewHeight - Margin);
    SaveFont := SelectObject(DC, Font.Handle);
    DrawFlags := DT_LEFT or DT_CALCRECT or WordBreak[WordWrap];
    DrawText(DC, PChar(Caption), -1, R, DrawFlags);
    SelectObject(DC, SaveFont);
    NewWidth := R.Right + Margin;
    NewHeight := R.Bottom + Margin;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

And I must be honest: it looks better.

Comment: If you implement CanAutoSize, I think the 2 Messages procedure from TLama version should no longer kept there? +1 for simplify though.

Comment: @Justmade No, you still need them. `TControl`, in which `AutoSize` is implemented, does take `Caption` nor `Font` in consideration.

Comment: +1, I was going to make a review of my answer but I wouldn't do it as efficient as you.

Comment: +1 what's with the +8? Is that a standard VCL-ism? It's going to lead to pain for high pixel density displays, or larger fonts. I think the margins ideally ought to be non-dimensionalised against a typical char height or width.

Comment: @NGLN, in TControl, AutoSize property and its dependencies are just inheritable behaviours to cope with alignment/docking, it does not to any "real" job. Look at DoCanAutoSize for example. And i think you are forgetting to call inherited.

Comment: @user539484 On `TControl` not doing any job you're quite right and I could have better said that `TControl` doesn't take ány property in consideration. Descendants still might however. As for forgetting to call inherited: I didn't. For a button, `TWinControl.CanAutoSize` hasn't much to offer since it has no children. Calling inherited is a choice, not a must. Note that `TWinControl.CanAutoSize` doesn't call inherited either.

Comment: Great and thorough answer. I almost feel ashamed I didn't use it :-)

Comment: I haven't "accepted" this answer as I haven't actually run the code myself, as it wasn't the solution I was looking for. See my (accepted) answer for the solution I used.

Comment: If you want TLama to be notified, then add @TLama to the comment. Also: if you didn't run the code, how did you deside it wasn't the solution? No hard feelings by the way.

Comment: @NGLN It wasn't the solution *for me* because I didn't want to add and maintain a new custom component when I could just add one line of code instead. OTOH If this was a problem I had to solve regularly I would try your solution.