# Delphi 7 application not loading STRINGTABLE resources on Windows 10

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-7

Been away from Delphi development for some time. Recently an old client contacted me with issues using an older Delphi 7 application on Windows 10 (x86 and x64). The application generally works fine, but internationalisation is not loading the correct string.

Here's the basic scenario.

1. An ASCII file named "String.rc" is generated from a translation spreadsheet:

```
Language LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_UK
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    cszTestString "English is good"
END

Language LANG_DUTCH, SUBLANG_DUTCH
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    cszTestString "En Nederlands is lekker"
END
```

2. A separate file called "String_IDs.pas" is generated to give an integer value to `cszTestString`:

```
unit String_IDs;
interface
const
    cszTestString = 1234;
```

2. "Strings.rc" is compiled using the Windows 10 SDK `rc.exe` to generate "Strings.res".
3. The .pas and resource files are compiled into the Delphi application by including the following in the project .dpr file:

```
    uses
        String_IDs in 'source\String_IDs.pas';

    {$R 'source\Strings.res'}
```

4. In code, set the locale to English or Dutch using:

```
    appLocale := (SUBLANG_ENGLISH_UK shl 10) or LANG_ENGLISH; // 2057
    if (isDutch) then
        appLocale := (SUBLANG_DUTCH shl 10) or LANG_DUTCH; // 1043
```

5. Set the threadlocale using:

```
    SetThreadLocale(appLocale);
```

6. Test loading the string resource in three different ways:

```
    // A: Using LoadStr
    stringA := LoadStr(cszTestString);

    // B: Using LoadString
    if (LoadString(0, cszTestString, szBuffer, Length(szBuffer)) > 0) then
        stringB := szBuffer;
    
    // C: Using LoadString in a different format
    try
    pstrBuffer := AllocMem(MAX_PATH);
    if (LoadString(0, cszTestString, pstrBuffer, MAX_PATH) > 0) then
        stringC := StrPas(pstrBuffer);
    finally
        FreeMem(pstrBuffer, MAX_PATH);
    end;
```

7. This was tested in a Windows XP (x86) VM. Everything works perfectly. In English, all three are "English is good". And in Dutch, all are "En Nederlands is lekker".
8. But I tested in Windows 10 (x86 and x64) VMs and the text is always "English is good". Have tried changing compatibility settings but without success.

Is there some other Windows API to use on Windows 10, or perhaps special compatibility settings for this older application?

Comment: Start with checking GetLastError when LoadString fails.

Comment: @Brian: LoadString doesn't fail, though. It just loads the English string.

Comment: Curious why you didn't simply use [`ResourceString`s](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Strings) from the very beginning?  You could have easily generated string declarations in a `.pas` file without involving `.rc`/`.res`, and then localized them as needed and let the RTL load the correct strings at runtime based on the app's localization.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would not do that with D7 because then I can't define Unicode strings (with Katakanas, Greek, Korean and Emojis) - resource files don't have any limitation.

Comment: Do you have Dutch added under `Preferred languages` available by going into `Start > Settings > Time & language > Language & region`?

Comment: @SilverWarior: Thanks for that comment! That step was not required on Windows XP. Went into `Settings > Time & Language > Language > Preferred languages`, then added  "Dutch (Netherlands)". In the same section, set the `Windows display language` to "Nederlands (Nederland)". Then rebooted, and now it works! `Region` and `Regional formats` were left as "United Kingdom" and "English (United Kingdom)" respectively. The software will now only display Dutch, though, and cannot be switched back to English except by changing the `Windows display language`.

Comment: I think that @RemyLebeau has a point about making this simpler. This is a quick-fix for now, but it is inconvenient as several settings need to change. A more convenient solution may involve creating language-specific resource DLLs and extracting `RT_STRING` resources from the DLLs.

Comment: Have now tested on both WIndows 10 x86 and x64, and the above steps work. The correct language strings are now displayed...but only for the "Windows display language". Unlike on Windows XP, you cannot dynamically switch between (say) English and Dutch - a reboot is required. Will add this detail to the question.

Comment: @AlainD As far as I know you don't need to change `Windows display language` just add `Dutch` to the list of preferred languages. Windows will then try to load application using `Windows display language` first and in case if the application does not support such language it will try to use one of the preferred languages in the same order as they are added to the list. And in case if application does not support nor `Windows display language` nor any of the preferred languages it will always fall back to English.

Comment: @SilverWarior: That is what I had hoped for, but I can confirm that on my W10 installation adding Dutch as a preferred language (and rebooting) was not enough. Also had to change the `Windows display language` (and reboot).

Comment: Have you perhaps tried using [SetThreadUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreaduilanguage) instead of [SetThreadLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale). It seems that Windows Vista introduced quite some changes of how multi-language supports is being handled in Windows.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Oh wow, thank you! Works on XP (x86), W10 (x86) and W10 (x64). I had to P/Invoke `SetThreadUILanguage` from kernel32.dll (the method is unknown to D7 natively) and that works for Dutch, German, Greek, etc. And no "preferred language" needs to be set. Amazing! Will knock up an answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment on Windows Vista and newer you should be using [SetThreadUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreaduilanguage) instead of [SetThreadLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale) to handle localised resources when they are stored inside the same resource file, provided they are tagged with specific language identifier.

Also based on [SetThreadLocale and SetThreadUILanguage for Localization on Windows XP and Vista](https://www.curlybrace.com/words/2008/06/10/setthreadlocale-and-setthreaduilanguage-for-localization-on-windows-xp-and-vista/) article it is not advisable of using [SetThreadUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreaduilanguage) as it might not have the desired effect on Windows XP. You should keep using [SetThreadLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale) on Windows XP

In order to learn how to check for Windows version the application is executed I recommend you read [Getting the Windows version?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8144702/3636228)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @SilverWarior for providing the answer. Here are some technical details for anyone who wants to reproduce them.

#### Step 1

Determine the Windows version. If you know it will be Windows 10 (or later) you can ignore. Save this result in a flag and run once at startup.

```
function IsWindows10() : Boolean;
var
    osVersionInfo: TOSVERSIONINFO;
begin
    { Following taken from MSDN (and duplicates removed)
        Windows 11                      TODO    ***
        Windows 10                      10.0    ***
        Windows Server 2016             10.0    ***
        Windows 8.1                     6.3     ***
        Windows Server 2012 R2          6.3     ***
        Windows 8                       6.2
        Windows 7                       6.1
        Windows Server 2008 R2          6.1
        Windows Server 2008             6.0
        Windows Vista                   6.0
        Windows Server 2003             5.2
        Windows XP 64-Bit               5.2
        Windows Embedded Std 2009       5.1 [Not stated explicitly on MSDN, from testing]
        Windows XP                      5.1
        Windows 2000                    5.0
        Windows NT 4.0                  4.0
        Windows Me                      4.90
        Windows 98                      4.10
        Windows 95                      4.0

        *** The application manifest must specifically target Windows 8.1 or 10, otherwise the
        version info for Windows 8 (6.2) will be returned. Since we cannot generate the proper
        manifest in Delphi 7, only 6.2 is returned.
        See the comment from @SilverWarior about alternative methods to extracting the Windows version. }

    ZeroMemory(@osVersionInfo, SizeOf(osVersionInfo));
    osVersionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(osVersionInfo);
    GetVersionEx(osVersionInfo);
    Result := (
        ((osVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 6) and             
            (osVersionInfo.dwMinorVersion >= 2)) or
        (osVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion = 10));
end;
```

#### Step 2

P/Invoke `SetThreadUILanguage` from kernel32.dll. This will not exist in Windows XP, but as we won't be calling the method (see next step) so that doesn't matter.

The Microsoft documentation for `SetThreadUILanguage` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreaduilanguage).

```
// Functions imported from external DLLs
function SetThreadUILanguage(wLanguageID: WORD) : WORD; stdcall;
    external 'Kernel32.dll' name 'SetThreadUILanguage';
```

#### Step 3

Write a method to set the GUI language.

```
procedure SetUILanguage(wLanguageID: WORD);
begin
    // Set the user interface language for the current thread
    // If this gets called a lot, save `IsWindows10` in a private member
    if (IsWindows10()) then
        SetThreadUILanguage(wLanguageID)
    else
        SetThreadLocale(wLanguageID);
end;
```

#### Step 4

Set the GUI language whenever required.

```
// Early in the application start, begin with English...
langID := ((SUBLANG_ENGLISH_UK shl 10) or LANG_ENGLISH);
SetUILanguage(langID);

// Later (in a galaxy far, far away) someone wants Czech...
langID := ((SUBLANG_DEFAULT shl 10) or LANG_CZECH);
SetUILanguage(langID);
```

Comment: Regarding your Step 1. If I'm not mistaken Delphi 6 does support compiling custom manifest file into your application. So you could write a proper manifest that specify correct windows version manually and pass it to compiler. Another way to determine windows version is by using WMI Query as stated in [How to detect true Windows version?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57128/3636228)

Comment: @SilverWarior: Good point. If you need the Windows version more precisely, those methods could be useful. But for the purposes of this question, this works fine. My comments in step 1 are overly large! ;o)

Comment: Nothing wrong with large comments especially if they contain possible return values from external API. This could be of great help if you need to make any changes to this code in the future and you don't have API documentation saved as part of your project.