# How to localize "Today" in the Delphi TMonthCalendar?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, monthcalendar

I have an issue with the default month calendar control on Windows and Delphi 2007.

By default, my dev environnemet is in French.

I need to translate the texts into Flemish:

- Dutch (Belgium), `nl-BE`, `$0813`

No worries, I use the *“Localizer”* tool and it’s ok.

On the other hand, with the [**TMonthCalendar** component](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TMonthCalendar), I have the character string *“aujourd'hui”* which is not displayed in Flemish; remaining in French as picture below :

[image: screen capture in nl-BE]

If you already noticed these behaviour, how did you fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think you can translate those strings. Control will use default user settings for those. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-controls?source=recommendations#localization

Answer (score 1):

Control `TMonthCalendar` is just a wrapper for Windows [Month Calendar Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-control-reference).

While it is possible to translate most of its elements using *Localizer* tool some of them still remain in the default Windows UI language. In order to change this you will have to change the current thread UI language by calling [SetThreadUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreaduilanguage) API function.

You can read more on this in [Delphi 7 application not loading STRINGTABLE resources on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78181647/3636228)

PS: You need to change Thread UI Language before `TMonthCalendar` is created otherwise this will not work.

Comment: I've been trying to 20 minutes to get the TMonthCalendar control to show up in another language. I added `SetThreadUILanguage($0813); InitMUILanguage($0813);  SetProcessPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME, 'nl-BE'#0, nil);` to my project file and it still shows in english. Can you show your suggestion of how to call **SetThreadUILanguage**?

Comment: Where do you call `SetThreadUILanguage`? I tried it in form constructor and it works. Well it changes the part of `TMonthCalendar ` that in OP case stays in French. But in order to change rest of calendar elements I guess you would still need use _Localizer_ tool to prepare localised string resource.

Comment: I tried it a) in the project file (before `Application.Initialize`), b) in the form's `OnCreate` event, and in the form's `constructor`.