# How to detect 32/64 platform?

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, delphi-xe7

I need to detect if the app is running on Win32/64.

Update: [People](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601089/detect-whether-current-windows-version-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) are reporting that relying on the [HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0] key is not a good idea.

Comment: That code is pretty gnarly. `LoadLibrary` returns an `HMODULE`. `GetModuleHandle('kernel32')` would be better than `LoadLibrary`. Dodgy use of `@`. Pointless initialisation of `vIsWow64`. Seems hard to believe that `IsWow64Process` would return `True` on a 32 bit OS.

Comment: @TLama The code in the question calls `IsWow64Process`. It doesn't just detect whether or not the function is exported.

Comment: @Altar I cannot reproduce. Your function, with its wrinkles, returns false on my 32 bit xp system. Note that I added diagnostics to prove that it reached the call to `IsWow64Process` and that call succeeded (returned true). I find it pretty hard to believe that `IsWow64Process` does not work.

Comment: The main thing is that I wanted you to notice `TOSVersion.Architecture` before moving on with your code. You can remove the code in your question and just use `TOSVersion.Architecture`.

Comment: @user246408 Serg, the dupe that you closed this for asks about D2007, which rather rules out `TOSVersion` answers. The question here is XE7.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry these questions are very close and I wanted to link them; did not know that voting for close as duplicate works this way now.

Comment: @user246408 I would simply paste a link into a comment. Like this: *Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523957/how-to-get-information-about-the-computer-32bit-or-64bit*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code that you present in the question has a few wrinkles, but it does work correctly. I suspect that you are not actually running that code, and have made an error and somehow posted the wrong code.

FWIW, you should use [`TOSVersion`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TOSVersion) from `System.SysUtils` to check the bitness of the underlying platform. The [`TOSVersion.Architecture`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TOSVersion.Architecture) property will tell you whether or not the underlying platform is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Even that's quite hard nowadays given that `GetVersionEx` lies! Still, `TOSVersion` does give you version numbers and a name so I guess it gets a good way there, modulo the `GetVersionEx` thing.